# C callback with JNA makes JRE crash

Tags: java, callback, crash, jvm, jna

I'm having problems handling callbacks in JNA.

I'm trying to use a C API that uses callbacks to handle several session events (logged in, logged out, connection problem...).
The session object (called `sp_session`) is an opaque struct. All the callbacks are registered in a `sp_session_callbacks` structure. According to the API, I am supposed to declare the callbacks object, and put it into a Config object that I will provide when creating the `sp_session` object. If I don't want to use certain callbacks, I am supposed to initialize them with `null`. The API is using the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Here is a snippet of the C header that's relevant to my problem:

```
#define SP_CALLCONV __stdcall

typedef struct sp_session sp_session; ///< Representation of a session

typedef enum sp_error {
    SP_ERROR_OK                        = 0,  
    SP_ERROR_BAD_API_VERSION           = 1,
        /* More errors */
} sp_error;

typedef struct sp_session_callbacks {
    /**
     * Called when login has been processed and was successful
     */
    void (SP_CALLCONV *logged_in)(sp_session *session, sp_error error);

    /**
     * Called when logout has been processed. Either called explicitly
     * if you initialize a logout operation, or implicitly if there
     * is a permanent connection error
     *
     * @param[in]  session    Session
     */
    void (SP_CALLCONV *logged_out)(sp_session *session);

    /**
     * Called when there is a connection error, and the library has problems
     * reconnecting to the Spotify service. Could be called multiple times (as
     * long as the problem is present) 
     */
    void (SP_CALLCONV *connection_error)(sp_session *session, sp_error error);

    /* More callbacks */
} sp_session_callbacks;

/**
 * Initialize a session. The session returned will be initialized, but you will need
 * to log in before you can perform any other operation
 */
SP_LIBEXPORT(sp_error) sp_session_create(const sp_session_config *config, sp_session **sess);
```

Here is my equivalent JNA code:

**The sp_session object**

```
public class sp_session extends PointerType{

    public sp_session(Pointer address) {
        super(address);
    }
    public sp_session() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**The sp_session_callbacks object, containing all the callbacks**

```
public class sp_session_callbacks extends Structure{
    public LoggedIn logged_in;
    public LoggedOut logged_out;
    public ConnectionError connection_error;
}
```

**The callbacks object (here is LoggedIn, but of course I have one for each callback)**

```
public interface LoggedIn extends StdCallCallback {
    public void logged_in(sp_session session, int error);
}
```

**The native library, with the declaration of all the methods**

```
public interface JLibspotify extends StdCallLibrary{
    int sessionCreate(sp_session_config config, PointerByReference sess);
    int sessionLogin(sp_session session, String username, String password);
    // All the other methods defined by the API
}
```

**And my main class, binding it all together**

```
public class Test{
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("libspotify");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JLibspotify lib = (JLibspotify)Native.loadLibrary("libspotify", JLibspotify.class);
        sp_session_config cfg = new sp_session_config();
        }
        sp_session_callbacks sessCallbacks = new sp_session_callbacks();
        LoggedIn loggedInCallback = new LoggedIn(){
        public void logged_in(sp_session session, int error) {
             System.out.println("logged_in() called");
            }

        };
        sessCallbacks.logged_in = loggedInCallback;

        cfg.session_callbacks = sessCallbacks;

        PointerByReference sessionPbr = new PointerByReference();

        int error_id = sessionCreate(cfg, sessionPbr); // CRASHES HERE

        sp_session mySession = new sp_session(sessionPbr.getValue());
    }
}
```

So, the sessionCreate function call makes the JRE crash with the trace at the end of the post `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) problematic frame: C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0xa3f4]`.

It looks like the logged_in callback is causing this, because when I set it to `null` it runs ok. Plus, if I initialize the `connection_error` callback, that has the exact same signature, it doesn't crash either.

I'm running version 3.2.7 of JNA. I tried with an anterior version (3.0.9) and it also failed.
I'm running the JDK 1.7 beta version, but I tried with the 1.6 and it also failed.

Thank you!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0499a3f4, pid=1368, tid=1344
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b129
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0xa3f4]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x01b79400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1344, stack(0x00340000,0x00390000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x1993053a

Registers:
EAX=0x19930522, EBX=0x100dc77c, ECX=0x00010004, EDX=0x1008d3e0
ESP=0x0038f58c, EBP=0x0038f5b4, ESI=0x0038f5a4, EDI=0x100b79b0
EIP=0x0499a3f4, EFLAGS=0x00210212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0038f58c)
0x0038f58c:   100dc77c 0038f5a4 00010004 0038f688
0x0038f59c:   05983de0 05981330 0598289c 05983de0
0x0038f5ac:   05983de0 00000014 0038f688 1008d3ea
0x0038f5bc:   05983de0 10030d77 0038fc44 100b79b0
0x0038f5cc:   ffffffff 1008d334 00000000 05983de0
0x0038f5dc:   1008d3e0 05983fc4 1008d9fd 0038f770
0x0038f5ec:   00000000 00000000 7275016a 055310b0
0x0038f5fc:   00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0499a3f4)
0x0499a3d4:   01 00 89 e5 57 56 8d 75 f0 53 83 ec 1c 8b 7d 14
0x0499a3e4:   8b 5f 4c 8b 03 89 4c 24 08 89 74 24 04 89 1c 24
0x0499a3f4:   ff 50 18 83 ec 0c 85 c0 0f 94 c0 0f b6 c0 85 c0
0x0499a404:   89 45 ec 75 19 8b 03 31 d2 89 54 24 08 89 74 24 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x19930522 is an unknown value
EBX=0x100dc77c is an unknown value
ECX=0x00010004 is an unknown value
EDX=0x1008d3e0 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0038f58c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01b79400
EBP=0x0038f5b4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01b79400
ESI=0x0038f5a4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01b79400
EDI=0x100b79b0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00340000,0x00390000],  sp=0x0038f58c,  free space=317k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0xa3f4]  Java_com_sun_jna_Native_initialize_1ffi_1type+0x1054
C  [libspotify.dll+0x8d3ea]  sp_error_message+0x35a
C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0xcb77]  Java_com_sun_jna_Native_initialize_1ffi_1type+0x37d7
C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0xc7c2]  Java_com_sun_jna_Native_initialize_1ffi_1type+0x3422
C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0x4561]  Java_com_sun_jna_Pointer__1getString+0xa31
C  [jna3666290841889849729.dll+0x4d2e]  Java_com_sun_jna_Function_invokeInt+0x2e
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invokeInt(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+315
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+214
j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+341
j  $Proxy0.sp_session_create(Lcom/nbarraille/jspotify/model/sp_session_config;Lcom/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference;)I+20
j  com.nbarraille.jspotify.main.Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+273
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x115f6d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b788e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x115fed]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa2507]
V  [jvm.dll+0xac867]
C  [javaw.exe+0x209e]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa23b]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa2c5]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x51194]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b429]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b3fc]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invokeInt(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+315
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+214
j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+341
j  $Proxy0.sp_session_create(Lcom/nbarraille/jspotify/model/sp_session_config;Lcom/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference;)I+20
j  com.nbarraille.jspotify.main.Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+273
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0182fc00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4664, stack(0x04170000,0x041c0000)]
  0x0182ac00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1728, stack(0x01b20000,0x01b70000)]
  0x01829800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=112, stack(0x04020000,0x04070000)]
  0x01826400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5836, stack(0x03ea0000,0x03ef0000)]
  0x01819800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4724, stack(0x03f80000,0x03fd0000)]
  0x01817800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3940, stack(0x01ad0000,0x01b20000)]
=>0x01b79400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1344, stack(0x00340000,0x00390000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01816400 VMThread [stack: 0x01a30000,0x01a80000] [id=3876]
  0x01843000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x040d0000,0x04120000] [id=4636]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 3630K [0x23450000, 0x239a0000, 0x289a0000)
  eden space 4416K,  82% used [0x23450000, 0x237db858, 0x238a0000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x238a0000, 0x238a0000, 0x23920000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23920000, 0x23920000, 0x239a0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x289a0000, 0x29450000, 0x33450000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x289a0000, 0x289a0000, 0x289a0200, 0x29450000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 860K [0x33450000, 0x34050000, 0x37450000)
   the space 12288K,   7% used [0x33450000, 0x33527190, 0x33527200, 0x34050000)
    ro space 10240K,  43% used [0x37450000, 0x3789ce40, 0x3789d000, 0x37e50000)
    rw space 12288K,  53% used [0x37e50000, 0x384c2710, 0x384c2800, 0x38a50000)

Code Cache  [0x01e90000, 0x01f20000, 0x03e90000)
 total_blobs=234 nmethods=82 adapters=88 free_code_cache=32972224 largest_free_block=0

Dynamic libraries:
0x00880000 - 0x008b0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe
0x778f0000 - 0x77a2d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77070000 - 0x77144000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75cf0000 - 0x75d3a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x60000000 - 0x60041000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\midas32.dll
0x61000000 - 0x61028000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_base.m32
0x67000000 - 0x67048000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_nt.m32
0x64000000 - 0x64021000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_registry.m32
0x62000000 - 0x6202d000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_extra.m32
0x65000000 - 0x6501a000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_net.m32
0x63000000 - 0x630a6000     C:\Program Files\BitDefender\BitDefender 2011\Active Virus Control\Midas_00078_002\plugin_fragments.m32
0x75e10000 - 0x75eb0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x775c0000 - 0x7766c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x75d50000 - 0x75d69000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x77670000 - 0x77711000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x76f00000 - 0x76fc9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77a50000 - 0x77a9e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77a30000 - 0x77a3a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x75d70000 - 0x75e0d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x74830000 - 0x749ce000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16661_none_420fe3fa2b8113bd\COMCTL32.dll
0x772f0000 - 0x77347000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x775a0000 - 0x775bf000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75eb0000 - 0x75f7c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x72740000 - 0x727fe000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x01b80000 - 0x01e89000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x746c0000 - 0x746f2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x73920000 - 0x7392c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x73330000 - 0x73350000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\java.dll
0x75d40000 - 0x75d45000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x733a0000 - 0x733b3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10259000     C:\Windows\System32\libspotify.dll
0x77150000 - 0x77185000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77a40000 - 0x77a46000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x75ba0000 - 0x75cbc000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75ab0000 - 0x75abc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x74ee0000 - 0x74f38000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x74e90000 - 0x74edf000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x754c0000 - 0x754d6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x75260000 - 0x7529b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x750a0000 - 0x750b7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75a40000 - 0x75a4b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75a30000 - 0x75a3c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x728a0000 - 0x728b6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\net.dll
0x75480000 - 0x754bc000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x75470000 - 0x75476000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73950000 - 0x73960000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x75340000 - 0x75384000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x71030000 - 0x71038000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x71020000 - 0x71030000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x71000000 - 0x71012000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x74fd0000 - 0x74fd5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74d30000 - 0x74d4c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74d20000 - 0x74d27000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x70c60000 - 0x70c66000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x71ba0000 - 0x71bd8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x73930000 - 0x7393f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x04990000 - 0x049e5000     C:\Users\nbarraille\AppData\Local\Temp\jna3666290841889849729.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\System32 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: com.nbarraille.jspotify.main.Test
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\System32
USERNAME=nbarraille
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3624108k(885020k free), swap 7246452k(3637664k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0-ea-b129), built on Feb 10 2011 07:43:39 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Mon Mar 07 14:25:08 2011
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

**EDIT:**
**Code to test the API in C**

```
#include "api.h"


/* --- Data --- */
const uint8_t g_appkey[] = {/*My appkey*/};


/* ---------------------------  SESSION CALLBACKS  ------------------------- */
static void logged_in(sp_session *sess, sp_error error){
    printf("logged_in() called: \n");
}

static void log_message(sp_session *sess, const char *data){
    printf("log_message() called %s : \n", data);
}

static void notify_main_thread(sp_session *sess){
    printf("notify_main_thread() called \n");
}

static sp_session_callbacks session_callbacks = {
    //.logged_in = (void*)&logged_in,
    //.notify_main_thread = (void*)&notify_main_thread,
    //.log_message = (void*)&log_message,
};

static sp_session_config spconfig = {
    .api_version = 7,
    .cache_location = "tmp",
    .settings_location = "tmp",
    .application_key = g_appkey,
    .application_key_size = sizeof(g_appkey),
    .user_agent = "jspotify",
    .callbacks = &session_callbacks,
    .userdata = NULL
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sp_session *sp;

    const char *username = "foo";
    const char *password = "bar";

    spconfig.application_key_size = sizeof(g_appkey);


    printf("Creating session \n");

    sp_error err = sp_session_create(&spconfig, &sp);

    if(err != 0){
        printf("Error occured: %d \n", err);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Login\n");
    sp_session_login(sp, username, password);

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it like this (without callbacks), the output is:

```
Creating session 
Login
```

And when I register the callbacks (uncomment the lines), it doesn't even print anything!

It looks like it doesn't print anything when a callback is called, because if I comment the `sp_session_login` line, only the declaration of `notify_main_thread` (which is the only one printed) will prevent the program from printing...

Comment: @Jason Sperske: This is my code.

Comment: @Jason Sperske: The linked question was not resolved, and the problem moved, that is why I opened a new one here.

Comment: So I've been able to get your project up and running in Eclipse and I'm getting the error you are talking about.  I'm still learning a lot about JNA, but I was wondering if sending a PointerByReference to sessionCreate is the source of what's going wrong?  I'm trying to understand how the code is referenced and it seems that you pass a reference before you associate the sp_session_callbacks stuct.  I don't know if this is at all helpful since there is a high chance that you know more about JNA than I do.

Comment: @Jason Sperske Thanks for looking into it. I don't believe this is the source of the problem because: 1/ I think this is how you are supposed to transform a ** in JNA. 2/ If you uncomment the cfg.logged_in = null; (line 77 of Test.java), the error goes away. Also, as you might see, the funny thing is that having connection_error declared doesn't crashes the JVM, even if it has the exact same signature as logged_in. So it makes me think it is not an argument type problem.

Comment: My guess would be that the error occurs because the sessionCreate() method actually tries to use the logged_in callback, and not the connection_error callback. So I was thinking, maybe it is trying to map this callback to a function pointer that is not declared? Maybe because of the __stdcall calling convention that got the method renamed? To cope with this, I tried replacing my homemade FunctionMapper by a StdCallFunctionMapper (to take care of the @bytes suffix), and renaming all the functions to their actual name. But it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about calling the callback.  I've been searching for some example of a Callback inside of a Structure and I haven't been able to find any example (I've been searching in Google Code search for projects with "extends StdCallCallback").  I've found some discussions where Timothy Wall seems to suggest that you can have a callback function pointer in a Structure but I don't see any code with that pattern.  The jLibSpotify (http://code.google.com/p/jlibspotify/) projects side steps this entirely with an extra DLL wrapper that makes the libSpotify more Java friendly.

Comment: @Jason Sperske The closest example I found to what I want to do is this: http://tutortutor.ca/cgi-bin/makepage.cgi?/tutorials/ct/mjnae in the "Revisiting Callbacks" section. I also sent an email to Timothy Wall concerning this problem through the JNA User mailing-list.

Comment: I had a look at this (on OS X rather than windows), and I get a crash even if I set `cfg.callbacks` to null. Note that I think that `sp_session_callbacks` should implement `Structure.ByRef` so that its inclusion in sp_session_config results in that structure containing a *pointer* to an `sp_session_callbacks` structure, rather than the structure inlined.

Comment: My crash was due to not setting some fields of cfg which needed to be set.

Comment: So your C example above doesn't print any callback messages? My example below does -- just the logging callback, because I don't have a spotify login. Try my code and see what that does (add the other callbacks to it)

Comment: @tgdavies Ok, thanks, probably the STCALLCONV was missing in mine. I will try yours tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @tgdavies So I adapted and tried your code, the log_message callback is called, but it looks like it's not establishing a connection (keeps trying to connect to different host with the following error : `log_message: 14:26:51.393 E [ap:1324] AP Socket Error: Hostname not found (11001)`, while in Java it is able to connect. I found it weird that the connection_error callback is not triggered though.

Comment: @tgdavies I created a new Question for the Java version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275384/cannot-connect-to-host-in-c-hostname-not-found-11001-on-windows-dns-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a C structure like:

```
struct Foo {
   Bar* bar
}
```

i.e. one which contains a pointer to another structure, your JNA implementation of Bar (`class Bar extends Structure`) must also implement the `Structure.ByReference` interface -- otherwise JNA will think that `struct Foo` contains an instance of `struct Bar` instead of a pointer to a `struct Bar`, and an illegal memory access will result as the C code interprets a value in the Bar instance as a pointer.

You need to add `implements Structure.ByReference` to the `sp_session_callbacks` class.

Thanks for inspiring me to look at JNA -- it's pretty cool!

Output of this code is:

```
sp_session_create returned 0
sp_session_login returned 0
log_message() called:14:16:53.825 I [ap:1388] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:4070

log_message() called:14:16:54.061 I [ap:938] Connected to AP: 193.182.8.11:4070

log_message() called:14:16:54.765 E [ap:3396] Connection error:  401
```

Process finished with exit code 0

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class JNATest {
//    static {
//        System.loadLibrary("libspotify");
//    }

    public interface JLibspotify extends Library {
        int sp_session_create(sp_session_config config, PointerByReference sess);

        int sp_session_login(sp_session session, String username, String password);
        // All the other methods defined by the API
    }

    public static class sp_session extends PointerType {

        public sp_session(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }

        public sp_session() {
            super();
        }
    }

    public static class sp_session_config extends Structure {
        public int api_version = 7; // The version of the Spotify API your application is compiled with.
        public String cache_location = ".";
        public String settings_location = ".";
        public Pointer application_key; // Your application key.
        public int application_key_size; // The size of the application key in bytes
        public String user_agent = "jspotify";
        public sp_session_callbacks callbacks; // Delivery callbacks for session events. NULL if not interested in any callbacks
        public Pointer userdata; // User supplied data for your application
        public boolean compress_playlists;
        public boolean dont_save_metadata_for_playlists;
        public boolean initially_unload_playlists;
    }

    public interface LoggedIn extends Callback {
        public void logged_in(sp_session session, int error);
    }

    public interface LoggedOut extends Callback {
        public void logged_out(sp_session session, int error);
    }

    public interface ConnectionError extends Callback {
        public void connection_error(sp_session session, int error);
    }

    public static class sp_session_callbacks extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{
    public LoggedIn logged_in; // Called when login has been processed and was successful
    public LoggedOut logged_out; // Called when logout has been processded. Either called explicitly if you initialize a logout operation, or implicitly if there is a permanent connection error.
    public Callback metadata_updated; // Called whenever metadata has been updated. If you have metadata cached outside of libspotify, you should purge your caches and fetch new versions.
    public ConnectionError connection_error; // Called when there is a connection error, and the library has problems reconnecting to the Spotify service. Could be called multiple times (as long as the problem is present)
    public Callback message_to_user; // Called when the acces point wants to display a message to the user. In the desktop client, these are shown in a blueish toolbar just below the search box.
    public Callback notify_main_thread; // Called when processing needs to take place on the main thread. You need to call sp_session_process_events() in the main thread to get libspotify to do more work. Failure to do so may cause request timeouts, or a lost connections.
    public Callback music_delivery; // Called when there is decompressed audio data available.
    public Callback play_token_lost; // Music has been paused because only one account may play music at the same time.
    public Callback log_message; // Logging callback
    public Callback end_of_track; // End of track. Called when the currently played track has reached its end.
    public Callback streaming_error; // Streaming error. Called when streaming cannot start or continue.
    public Callback userinfo_updated; // Called after user info (anything related to sp_user objects) have been updated.
    public Callback start_playback; // Called when audio playback should start. For this to work correctly the application must also implement get_audio_buffer_stats(). This function is called from an internal session thread - you need to have proper synchronization. This function must never block.
    public Callback stop_playback; // Called when audio playback should stop. For this to work correctly the application must also implement get_audio_buffer_stats(). This function is called from an internal session thread - you need to have proper synchronization. This function must never block.
    public Callback get_audio_buffer_stats; // Called to query application about its audio buffer. This function is called from an internal session thread - you need to have proper synchronization! This function must never block.
}

    private static final char[] APP_KEY ={/* Appkey here**/;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JLibspotify lib = (JLibspotify) Native.loadLibrary("spotify", JLibspotify.class);
        sp_session_config cfg = new sp_session_config();
        Pointer ptr = new Memory(APP_KEY.length);
        ptr.write(0, toBytes(APP_KEY), 0, APP_KEY.length);
        cfg.application_key = ptr;
        cfg.application_key_size = APP_KEY.length;
        sp_session_callbacks sessCallbacks = new sp_session_callbacks();
        LoggedIn loggedInCallback = new LoggedIn() {
            public void logged_in(sp_session session, int error) {
                System.out.println("logged_in() called");
            }

        };
        ConnectionError connectionErrorCallback = new ConnectionError() {

            public void connection_error(sp_session session, int error) {
                System.out.println("connection_error() called");
            }
        };
        LoggedOut loggedOutCallback = new LoggedOut() {

            public void logged_out(sp_session session, int error) {
                System.out.println("logged_out() called");
            }
        };

        sessCallbacks.logged_in = loggedInCallback;
        sessCallbacks.connection_error = connectionErrorCallback;
        sessCallbacks.logged_out = loggedOutCallback;
        sessCallbacks.log_message = new Callback() {
            public void callback(sp_session session, String message) {
                System.out.println("log_message() called:" + message);
            }
        };
        cfg.callbacks = sessCallbacks;
        PointerByReference sessionPbr = new PointerByReference();

        int error_id = lib.sp_session_create(cfg, sessionPbr); // CRASHES HERE
        System.out.println("sp_session_create returned " + error_id);
//
        sp_session mySession = new sp_session(sessionPbr.getValue());
        error_id = lib.sp_session_login(mySession, "foo", "bar");
        System.out.println("sp_session_login returned " + error_id);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public static byte[] toBytes(char[] key){
        byte[] b = new byte[key.length];
        for(int i =0; i < key.length; i++){
            if(key[i] > 127){
                b[i] = (byte)(key[i] - 256);
            }else{
                b[i] = (byte)key[i];
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Here's a C program which does the same thing (with fewer callbacks -- you'll need to add more). It's for OS X so you may need to change the `#include`. As I can't get spotify in Australia I can't test it to see whether a successful login hits a callback, but the logging callback works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libspotify/api.h>

void SP_CALLCONV log_message(sp_session *session, const char *data) {
        fprintf(stderr,"log_message: %s\n", data);
        fflush(stderr);
}

void SP_CALLCONV connection_error(sp_session *session, sp_error error) {
        fprintf(stderr,"connection_error: %d\n", error);
        fflush(stderr);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        static byte APP_KEY[] = {
                /*the API key */};
        static sp_session_callbacks callbacks;
        callbacks.log_message = log_message;
        callbacks.connection_error = connection_error;
        static sp_session_config cfg;
        cfg.callbacks = &callbacks;
        cfg.api_version = 7;
        cfg.cache_location = ".";
        cfg.settings_location = ".";
        cfg.user_agent = "jspotify";
        cfg.application_key = APP_KEY;
        cfg.application_key_size = sizeof(APP_KEY);

        sp_session* mySession;
        int code = sp_session_create(&cfg, &mySession);
        printf("sp_session_create returned %d\n", code);
        sp_session_login(mySession, "foo", "bar");
        printf("sp_session_login returned %d\n", code);
        sleep(10);
}
```

If the C program calls callbacks which the Java version doesn't, then perhaps there's something wrong with the use of jna -- if not, perhaps there's something more to understand about spotify and when it calls callbacks. I agree that the docs seem to say that a successful login will call a callback, but perhaps they're out of date?

Comment: You are right about the ByReference that should be added to the `sp_session_callbacks`, as `sp_session_cfg` needs a `sp_session_cfg*`. It got me rid of the JVM crash. I got the log_message callback working like you did (without the error 401, which is a bad credentials error), but my `logged_in`, `connection_error` and `logged_out` callbacks are still not firing, even though they should have (I have a connection error at first when trying to connect on port 4070, then connected on port 80 should fire `logged_in` and a call to `sp_logout()` should fire `logged_out`)

Comment: @nathanb I think it might be time (for you :-) to write a C version of this test and see if that calls the callbacks as we expect.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. So I used a simplified version of one of the example that is given with the API (http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/jukebox.c-example.html). I can't get it to work with any callback this time. I added the C code and a description of my problems at the end of my initial post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I finally got the C program to work (I just didn't run it as Administrator). It turns out that the callbacks I see in C are the same that the one in JNA, so it is probably not working as described in the documentation... It looks like a lot of fun in perspective... Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: You've probably figured this out already, but just for completeness - to get the callbacks firing, you've gotta call 'sp_session_process_events' when the notify_main_thread callback is fired -> otherwise it'll just happily sit there.